# SQL - show all rows in table using group by and where

Tags: sql

I have the following problem: I should print the count of sunk ships of all countries. So I write the following:

```
use ships;

select CLASSES.CLASS, COUNT(*)
from CLASSES
left join SHIPS on CLASSES.CLASS = SHIPS.CLASS
left join OUTCOMES on NAME = SHIP
where RESULT = 'sunk'
group by CLASSES.CLASS;
```

but if some country doesn't have a sunk ship it will not appear in result. But I want every country to be in the result and if it doesn't have sunk ships to shop 0 for count.
How can I achieve that?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Uh, your query has no indication that it is selecting a country.

Comment: Yes, you are right! Country should be replaced with CLASS or reverse (the problem doesn't change).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way to do this is using `LEFT JOIN`, but with the condition in the `ON` clause:

```
select c.CLASS, COUNT(o.RESULT)
from CLASSES c left join
     SHIPS s
     on c.CLASS = s.CLASS left join
     OUTCOMES o
     on s.NAME = o.SHIP and
        o.RESULT = 'sunk'
group by c.CLASS;
```

Notice that the table aliases also make the query easier to write and to read.

Also, I have to guess what tables the columns belong in.  When you use qualified column names from the beginning, then there is no guessing.

Comment: Thank you very much! You missed `s` after `left join SHIPS`. That's the best and the accepted answer. So now we have 0 when in rows in which classes we don't have ships, because COUNT(NULL) will not add 1 to the accumulating count actually, right?

Comment: @DPM . . . Correct. `COUNT(<whatever>)` counts the non-NULL values.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the SQL dialect you use. If you use Informix as a database, you can use nvl() function:

```
SELECT <whatever>, nvl(ships, 0) AS ship_num FROM SHIPS;
```

Using Sqlite3 you can use coalesce() function:

```
SELECT <whatever>, coalesce(ships, 0) AS ship_num FROM SHIPS;
```

etc. All dialects of SQL will have one of such functions but they all named differently. But the basic principle is the same - if the value I get is NULL, use the provided value instead - zero in your case, but it can be anything, even column value or a string "Not specified" etc. If you provide the database you're querying against, I can give you the function to use.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the code is sufficient as a sample of the problem regardless country not mentioned every where in the code, there are many ways to count, and my favorite way is using `if`(mysql) or `case` (sql server) inside `count`..

**mysql** - using `if`

```
use ships;

select CLASSES.CLASS, COUNT(IF(RESULT = 'sunk', 1, NULL))
from CLASSES
left join SHIPS on CLASSES.CLASS = SHIPS.CLASS
left join OUTCOMES on NAME = SHIP
group by CLASSES.CLASS;
```

**sqlserver** - using `case`

```
use ships;

select CLASSES.CLASS, COUNT(CASE WHEN RESULT = 'sunk' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)
from CLASSES
left join SHIPS on CLASSES.CLASS = SHIPS.CLASS
left join OUTCOMES on NAME = SHIP
group by CLASSES.CLASS;
```

Comment: Thanks you very much! This helps me. Your first row should be select CLASSES.CLASS, COUNT(IF(RESULT = 'sunk', 1, NULL)).